# Open my mouth and twist my ear

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Open my mouth and twist my ear
>   Like you have done since yesteryear.
>   I'll do what I have done the most:
>   I'll hold my ground and stand my post.
>
> When I'm ready, when I'm sated
>   I'll give you something not belated.
>   If you feel rushed—if time is dear—
>   I sometimes open from the rear.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not intimately familiar with these objects, but I wonder whether you are

> a curbside mailbox of the sort commonly used in the USA (but I think scarcely anywhere else).

```
Open my mouth and twist my ear
Like you have done since yesteryear.
I'll do what I have done the most:
I'll hold my ground and stand my post.
```

> Mostly just description, but there are a couple of puns here if my guess is correct. These things are mounted in the *ground* by a *post* -- and also used as a receptacle for incoming *post*. "Yesteryear" because they have been around for a while, and physical mail is rather an old-fashioned thing these days. I guess the "ear" is the flag that indicates the presence of mail awaiting collection.

```
When I'm ready, when I'm sated
I'll give you something not belated.
If you feel rushed—if time is dear—
I sometimes open from the rear.
```

> You would, at any rate, *hope* that your mail isn't belated. Traditionally, this style of mailbox opens up at the front -- the piece of metal with the slot for mail to be posted into pivots downward. But there are models that open at the back instead, the idea being that the front is outside your property (for easy access for the postman) and the back is inside (for easy access for you).

Comment: "Intimately." Ha! This is correct and +1.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are a:

> Slot Machine

Open my mouth and twist my ear

> Put a coin in it's mouth and pull the handle

Like you have done since yesteryear.

> Slot machines have traditionally been this way

I'll do what I have done the most:

I'll hold my ground and stand my post.

> Slot machines are normally not so mobile

When I'm ready, when I'm sated

> When the machine's wheel/RNG determines you've spun enough

I'll give you something not belated.

> You win

If you feel rushed—if time is dear—

> You get a rush from winning

I sometimes open from the rear.

> This is how some are serviced - coinage pulled and added from a service area behind

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are a

> [PEZ dispenser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pez)

Open my mouth and twist my ear /
Like you have done since yesteryear.

> To get the PEZ out

I'll do what I have done the most: / 
I'll hold my ground and stand my post.

> They're shaped like a pole, and stand up.

When I'm ready, when I'm sated / 
I'll give you something not belated.

> The PEZ, of course!

If you feel rushed—if time is dear— / 
I sometimes open from the rear.

> Instead of eating them one by one, you can open the bottom to get them all out at once!

Comment: Good guess... I always am amused at the lateral thinking around here! The mouth clue fits, but I don't get the ear part. Also, there are a few more puns/clues which should make the answer undeniable.

Comment: @Chowzen Yeah, I thought the ear was a stretch. My idea was that you can use the ears to open the mouth, in a rotating motion.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're a

> covered lock

```
Open my mouth and twist my ear 
Like you have done since yesteryear.
I'll do what I have done the most:
I'll hold my ground and stand my post.
```

> You must swing the cover aside and turn the key to use - and they used to be very common (though less so now)
>  Once locked it could be considered to hold its ground.

```
When I'm ready, when I'm sated
I'll give you something not belated.
If you feel rushed—if time is dear—
I sometimes open from the rear.
```

> Once unlocked, whatever is behind it can be obtained
>   The other side of the lock can be a mechanism that doesn't require a key

Answer (score 2):

Open my mouth and twist my ear

Like you have done since yesteryear.

I'll do what I have done the most:

I'll hold my ground and stand my post.

> Coin operated treat dispenser.

When I'm ready, when I'm sated

I'll give you something not belated.

> Once the coin has hit the trigger, the treat is released

If you feel rushed—if time is dear—

I sometimes open from the rear.

> Depending on the design one can retrieve the contents from the rear, where the treats are inserted. By key (commercial machine) or by simple latch (desktop treat)

Answer (score 1):

Even though a different answer has been accepted, I would contend that you're a

> manual can opener

```
Open my mouth and twist my ear
```

> The "mouth" is the cutting wheels and the "ear" is the crank.

```
Like you have done since yesteryear.
```

> This type of can opener has been around, more or less unchanged, for a long time.

```
I'll do what I have done the most:
I'll hold my ground and stand my post.
```

> Can openers don't work very well if you allow the can and opener to move around.

```
When I'm ready, when I'm sated
I'll give you something not belated.
```

> If the cutting blade of the opener is the "mouth", then the lid is what it eats. When the opener is "sated", the can is open and its contents are still fresh.

```
If you feel rushed—if time is dear—
I sometimes open from the rear.
```

> If you're not paying attention, you might open the bottom of the can instead.

Answer (score 1):

The answer the riddle made me think of was:

> A horse.

Open my mouth and twist my ear / Like you have done since yesteryear.

> It's reputed to be common among horse buyers to look in the horse's mouth to evaluate their teeth.  (Hence the saying about "don't look a gift horse in the mouth.")  Twisting a horse's ear, on the other hand, would be a cruel form of discipline.  And both these are presumably ancient customs.

I'll do what I have done the most / I'll hold my ground and stand my post.

> Most of the time horses graze without shifting position very much.  And the "post" part would refer to tying a horse's reins to a post when going inside some place briefly.

When I'm ready, when I'm sated / I'll give you something not belated.

> Feed a race horse and it will be ready to compete.

If you feel rushed -- if time is dear -- / I sometimes open from the rear.

> Referring to using horse manure as fertilizer, to "rush" the growth of crops.

(The only part I would feel is really much of a stretch would be in the subject of the riddle *asking* you to twist its ear, when mostly the subject would greatly prefer it if you *didn't*.)